# git hook to reload database on checkout when schema changes

Tags: git

Our database schema is generated programmatically from files in our /models directory. I'd like to figure out a git hook I can use so that when doing a checkout or merge, I compare the SHA1 of the /models directory, and if it is not the same as what I had before, I re-initialize the test database and reload our fixtures.

Is it possible to lookup the SHA1 of the /models directory, save it in a variable, and then compare it to the results after completing the checkout/merge?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails, [guard-migrate](https://github.com/glanotte/guard-migrate) is a decent solution for this which operates at a different level than git. It monitors db/schema.rb for changes, and then updates the database if necessary. Just be sure to turn it off while working on writing migrations.